# How to deploy Visual Studio add-ins via ClickOnce?

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce, add-in, extensibility

Is is possible to deploy VS add-ins using ClickOnce? How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Rob: The links you have provided is Add-in's for Applications (aka MS Office), not for Add-in's for Visual Studio (as I understand the question). The Add-in object model in Visual Studio does not support ClickOnce - unfortunately.

To deploy Add-in's for Visual Studio, visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393694.aspx.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Securing and Deploying Add-Ins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc175947.aspx). And the subtopic [Securing Add-ins by Using ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc175918.aspx).

I haven't personally used them, but I found them while searching with a similar question as yours.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you cannot do this. ClickOnce is designed for side-effect free deployments, and don't impact registry (except perhaps for file associations) or "Program Files" (having their own repository).

I'm pretty sure you'll need msi for this.

Comment: Actually, registry changes are no longer required. You can just drop a registration file (.AddIn) in the appropriate directory. That said, I don't think ClickOnce gives you any choice in target directory, nor any hooks into the "installation".